# Slide a window through an image, and change the value of center pixel in window based on the average value of the sliding window

Tags: python, image, opencv, scipy, python-imaging-library

I am trying to slide a `5 by 5` 2D window across a gray image.
If all the pixels within that 2D window equal to 200, replace the center pixel value within the window with 100.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from scipy.signal import convolve2d as conv2

image = cv2.imread("testImage.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

output = (conv2(gray, np.ones((5, 5), dtype=int), 'valid') == 200).astype(int)
```

I am not sure where to go from here or how to do this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it almost correct.  The output of your convolve2d thing is a boolean array that has True where you want the value changed.  You can use that as a fancy index into the original array, one of numpy's best features.  Note that you need "same", not "valid", to make sure the output array had the right size.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve2d as conv2

image = cv2.imread("splat.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
box = np.ones((3,3),dtype=int)
output = conv2(gray, box, 'same') == 200
gray[output] = 100
```